# vb.net stream_writer encoding

Tags: vb.net, encoding, stream, writer

Please to tell me how to convert a string message to ascii chars to send it over the stream writer, I have been struggling for hours/days , the client controller is receiving System.Byte[]  .
I think I am not correctly sending ascii char sequence.

```
   Public Sub sub_send(ByVal str_my_msg As String)

        Dim string_converted_to_ascii_chars As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str_my_msg )

        stream_writer = New StreamWriter(my_client.GetStream)

        stream_writer.Write(string_converted_to_ascii_chars )

        stream_writer.Flush()

       
    End Sub
```

Comment: Streams should be declared in a `Using...End Using` block so they will be disposed.

Comment: The client needs to interpret the bytes as ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub sub_send(ByVal str_my_msg As String)
    Dim string_converted_to_ascii_chars As [Char]() = str_my_msg.ToCharArray()

    stream_writer = New StreamWriter(my_client.GetStream)
    stream_writer.Write(string_converted_to_ascii_chars)
    stream_writer.Flush()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you RedneckSolutions , it worked :) thanks alot.